# How to resolve In-memory PM2 is out-of-date

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, pm2

### Amazon AWS Ubuntu server

```
~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

### Problem: PM2 is out-of-date

```
$ pm2 list

>>>> In-memory PM2 is out-of-date, do:
>>>> $ pm2 update
In memory PM2 version: 2.4.6
Local PM2 version: 3.0.3
```

### Tried

```
pm2 update
```

... works until I reboot

### Tried

```
npm remove pm2 -g
which pm2 
npm install pm2@latest -g
which pm2
sudo reboot
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem and could solve it with re-creating the startup script. Try the following steps:

- delete current process

  ```
  pm2 delete nameOfProcess
  ```
- unload current startup script

  ```
  pm2 unstartup systemd
  ```
- update pm2

  ```
  pm2 update
  ```
- enable startup script

  ```
  pm2 startup //copy paste the output
  ```
- start process again

  ```
  pm2 start nameOfProcess
  ```
- save current config

  ```
  pm2 save
  ```

Comment: All of these + `rm -rf /home/ec2-user/.pm2` where ec2-user is you current user

Comment: @Shirker `rm -rf /home/ec2-user/.pm2` was not necessary in my case for `Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS` and `pm2@5.1.0`